# Unknown pointer notification

Tags: string, visual-c++, pointers

I've got some difficulties to understand the following declaration in `VC++`:

```
 int numChoice=figureCB->SelectedIndex;//CB=COMBO BOX
 char Choice=((String^) figureCB->Items[numChoice])[0];//
```

It's the second line that causes me the problem. Why is 'String^' in brackets?

Why is:

```
     char Choice=(String^ figureCB->Items[numChoice])[0];//
```

uncorrect?

Usually, when I declare a `pointer` on a class, I write:

```
ClassName *pointername;
```

or, when it points to a managed class:

```
ClassName ^pointername;
```

Comment: You used a cast because the item in a combo box is an object, not necessarily a string.  Which in fact requires you to use ToString() instead of a cast.

Answer (score 0):

This is CLI code, not pure C++, (what you have called 'managed').
The brackets are a cast.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of You! Uwe_98